How to open grib2 file with xarray in python?
import xarray as xr
import cfgrib
import eccodes
import pandas as pd
data = xr.open_dataset(r"C:\Users\new\forecast_data.grib2", engine = "cfgrib")

I want to read this file using xarray. The error is:
unrecognized engine cfgrib must be one of: ['netcdf4', 'scipy', 'store']
eccodes is installed in my system.
I checked on Anaconda prompt
(nih) C:\Users\new>python -m eccodes selfcheck
C:\Users\new\anaconda3\envs\nih\Lib\site-packages\gribapi\__init__.py:23: UserWarning: ecCodes 2.31.0 or higher is recommended. You are running version 2.26.0
  warnings.warn(
Found: ecCodes v2.26.0.
Library: C:\Users\new\anaconda3\envs\nih\Library\bin\eccodes.dll
Definitions: /MEMFS/definitions
Samples: /MEMFS/samples
Your system is ready.

I want to read a grib2 file. I have previously worked with netCDF files. I need to read this grib2 file or convert it to netCDF so that I may open it using xarray. I tried pynio engine. It gave me the same result.

From the documentation, looks like you can use cfgrib.open_datasets to convert grib2 file into an array of xarray.core.dataset.Dataset objects instead
import cfgrib
data = cfgrib.open_datasets(r"C:\Users\new\forecast_data.grib2")


I tried this code. It is still showing the same error: unrecognized engine cfgrib must be one of: ['netcdf4', 'scipy', 'store']

@SehajKaur hmm that's strange. I was able to reproduce the issue you have but have no trouble using cfgrib.open_datasets. Could you share the stack trace? btw which version of cfgrib you're using?

d = xr.open_dataset(r"C:\Users\new\download.grib", engine = 'cfgrib')
Traceback (most recent call last):
Cell In[10], line 1
d = xr.open_dataset(r"C:\Users\new\download.grib", engine = 'cfgrib')
File ~\anaconda3\envs\nih\Lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py:574 in open_dataset
backend = plugins.get_backend(engine)
File ~\anaconda3\envs\nih\Lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\plugins.py:205 in get_backend
raise ValueError(
ValueError: unrecognized engine cfgrib must be one of: ['netcdf4', 'scipy', 'store']

cfgrib.version
Out[11]: '0.9.8.5'

@SehajKaur Oh I see you're still having the line d = xr.open_dataset(r"C:\Users\new\download.grib", engine = 'cfgrib') in your code. You need to replace it with the line d = cfgrib.open_datasets(r"C:\Users\new\forecast_data.grib2") instead

Hey... I could solve the error using  d = xr.open_dataset(r"C:\Users\new\download.grib", engine = 'cfgrib')... the versions of modules xarray and cfgrib were incompatible. I downgraded the xarray version. It worked! Thanks for your help

@SehajKaur Cool, that works too I guess
